# Ansible playbook output to list all failed items at the end

Tags: ansible

is there a way to display list of failed items and changed items at the end of playbook results instead of just the numbers on how many failed, changed and ok?

Please suggest this is for reporting purpose.

Comment: You could write a [callback plugin](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/plugins/callback.html) that does that for you.  It's possible someone else has already done that.  Depending on your needs, you may also want to take a look at [ARA](https://github.com/openstack/ara).

Comment: I don't know why this question was downvoted. I find this question very interesting and a comment above to be a good answer.

Comment: Thank you for guidance , i will look into it. Basically i created OS compliance module for Redhat . It runs bunch of tasks and at then end i wanted to show a report which gives the details

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin I agree with you. This type of requirement is not common across the board, my feeling is people didn't understand what i am trying to accomplish here. This is not a easy task to accomplish and if we get solution for this and print output it will add lot of value for Ansible Compliance Automation